# Scanner+Parser created for a Compiler

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, compiler-construction, variable-assignment, lexical-analysis

I have successfully created a scanner for a parser which in turn will be used with a code generator to create a complete compiler. My parser right now can successfully parse assignments, `if, if-else, while-do`, comparisons, `read and write` commands. The only problem I have is when trying to assign something after a `while-do` or `if/if-else` it fails.

**Update: I can actually assign variables after an `if\if else` and `while-do` statements, but another problem has been found. I cannot make any nested `if/if else` or `while-do` statements. So now the problem is how to fix nested boolean and loop statements.**

---

The way my parser works with `if-then` statements is:

```
if z < 4 then
  z := z + 7
end
```

What is written out is:

```
Statements
    If
        LESS
            z
            4
        Statements
            Assign
                z
                ADD
                    z
                    7
```

It recognizes the if and runs a method called `if_statement()` which scans the `if` token, sets the comparison equal to a variable, scans the `then` token, and sets the statements after then to a variable. Next, in order to accommodate for both `if` and `if-else` statements, I use a method called lookahead() which looks at the next token. If it sees `end`, it returns the variables to be written to a text document. If it sees `else`, it the scans the `else` token, and assigns the statements after to a variable, then looks for the `end` token. Then it returns all the variables to be written to a text document.

The code for just this method is as follows:

```
def if_statement():
  scanner.consume(Token.IF)
  condition = comparison()
  scanner.consume(Token.THEN)
  then = statements()
  if scanner.lookahead() == Token.END:
    scanner.consume(Token.END)
    return If_AST(condition, then)
  else:
    scanner.consume(Token.ELSE)
    otherwise = statements()
    scanner.consume(Token.END)
    return If_Else_AST(condition, then,  otherwise)
```

If_AST and If_Else_AST are as follows:

```
class If_AST:
  def __init__(self, condition, then):
    self.condition = condition
    self.then = then
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'if ' + repr(self.condition) + ' then ' + \
                   repr(self.then) + ' end'
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('If', level) + \
           self.condition.indented(level+1) + \
           self.then.indented(level+1)


class If_Else_AST:
  def __init__(self,  condition,  then,  otherwise):
    self.condition = condition;
    self.then = then;
    self.otherwise = otherwise;
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'if ' + repr(self.condition) + ' then ' +\
                    repr(self.then) + ' else ' + \
                    repr(self.otherwise) + ' end'
  def indented(self,  level):
    return indent('If-Else',  level) + \
            self.condition.indented(level+1) + \
            self.then.indented(level+1) + \
            self.otherwise.indented(level+1)
```

For `while-do`, it instead replaces `if` with `while` and `then` with `do`. But for good measure, I will also include the while method and class:

```
def while_statement():
  scanner.consume(Token.WHILE)
  condition = comparison()
  scanner.consume(Token.DO)
  body = statements()
  scanner.consume(Token.END)
  return While_AST(condition, body)



class While_AST:
  def __init__(self, condition, body):
    self.condition = condition
    self.body = body
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'while ' + repr(self.condition) + ' do ' + \
                      repr(self.body) + ' end'
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('While', level) + \
           self.condition.indented(level+1) + \
           self.body.indented(level+2)
```

I realize that my parser does not support `else if` statements. `Else if` statements are not part of this exercise.

And lastly, just in case someone needs to see everything, my full code so far is as follows:

```
import re
import sys

class Scanner:
  '''The interface comprises the methods lookahead and consume.
  Other methods should not be called from outside of this class.'''

  def __init__(self, input_file):
    '''Reads the whole input_file to input_string, which remains constant.
      current_char_index counts how many characters of input_string have
      been consumed.
      current_token holds the most recently found token and the
      corresponding part of input_string.'''
    # source code of the program to be compiled
    self.input_string = input_file.read()
    # index where the unprocessed part of input_string starts
    self.current_char_index = 0
    # a pair (most recently read token, matched substring of input_string)
    self.current_token = self.get_token()

  def skip_white_space(self):
    '''Consumes all characters in input_string up to the next
      non-white-space character.'''
    if (self.current_char_index >= len(self.input_string) - 1):
        return

    while self.input_string[self.current_char_index].isspace():
        self.current_char_index += 1

  def get_token(self):
    '''Returns the next token and the part of input_string it matched.
      The returned token is None if there is no next token.
      The characters up to the end of the token are consumed.'''
    self.skip_white_space()
    # find the longest prefix of input_string that matches a token
    token, longest = None, ''
    for (t, r) in Token.token_regexp:
        match = re.match(r, self.input_string[self.current_char_index:])
        if match and match.end() > len(longest):
            token, longest = t, match.group()
    # consume the token by moving the index to the end of the matched part
    self.current_char_index += len(longest)
    return (token, longest)

  def lookahead(self):
    '''Returns the next token without consuming it.
      Returns None if there is no next token.'''
    return self.current_token[0]

  def consume(self, *tokens):
    '''Returns the next token and consumes it, if it is in tokens.
      Raises an exception otherwise.
      If the token is a number or an identifier, its value is returned
      instead of the token.'''
    current = self.current_token

    if (len(self.input_string[self.current_char_index:]) == 0):
        self.current_token = (None, '')         
    else:
        self.current_token = self.get_token()   
    if current[0] in tokens:         
        if current[0] is Token.ID:  
            #print("ID")
            return current[1]   
        elif current[0]  is Token.NUM:
            #print("NUM")
            return current[1]
        else:                                   
            return current[0]                   
    else:                                       
        raise Exception('non-token detected')   


class Token:
  # The following enumerates all tokens.
  DO    = 'DO'
  ELSE  = 'ELSE'
  READ  = 'READ'
  WRITE = 'WRITE'
  END   = 'END'
  IF    = 'IF'
  THEN  = 'THEN'
  WHILE = 'WHILE'
  SEM   = 'SEM'
  BEC   = 'BEC'
  LESS  = 'LESS'
  EQ    = 'EQ'
  GRTR  = 'GRTR'
  LEQ   = 'LEQ'
  NEQ   = 'NEQ'
  GEQ   = 'GEQ'
  ADD   = 'ADD'
  SUB   = 'SUB'
  MUL   = 'MUL'
  DIV   = 'DIV'
  LPAR  = 'LPAR'
  RPAR  = 'RPAR'
  NUM   = 'NUM'
  ID    = 'ID'

  # The following list gives the regular expression to match a token.
  # The order in the list matters for mimicking Flex behaviour.
  # Longer matches are preferred over shorter ones.
  # For same-length matches, the first in the list is preferred.
  token_regexp = [
      (DO,    'do'),
      (ELSE,  'else'),
      (READ,    'read'),
      (WRITE,  'write'),
      (END,   'end'),
      (IF,    'if'),
      (THEN,  'then'),
      (WHILE, 'while'),
      (SEM,   ';'),
      (BEC,   ':='),
      (LESS,  '<'),
      (EQ,    '='),
      (NEQ,    '!='),
      (GRTR,  '>'),
      (LEQ,   '<='),
      (GEQ,   '>='),
      (ADD,   '[+]'), # + is special in regular expressions
      (SUB,   '-'),
      (MUL,   '[*]'),
      (DIV,   '[/]'),
      (LPAR,  '[(]'), # ( is special in regular expressions
      (RPAR,  '[)]'), # ) is special in regular expressions
      (ID,    '[a-z]+'),
      (NUM,   '[0-9]+'),
  ]


def indent(s, level):
  return '    '*level + s + '\n'

# Each of the following classes is a kind of node in the abstract syntax tree.
# indented(level) returns a string that shows the tree levels by indentation.

class Program_AST:
  def __init__(self, program):
    self.program = program
  def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.program)
  def indented(self, level):
    return self.program.indented(level)

class Statements_AST:
  def __init__(self, statements):
    self.statements = statements
  def __repr__(self):
    result = repr(self.statements[0])
    for st in self.statements[1:]:
        result += '; ' + repr(st)
    return result
  def indented(self, level):
    result = indent('Statements', level)
    for st in self.statements:
        result += st.indented(level+1)
    return result

class If_AST:
  def __init__(self, condition, then):
    self.condition = condition
    self.then = then
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'if ' + repr(self.condition) + ' then ' + \
                   repr(self.then) + ' end'
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('If', level) + \
           self.condition.indented(level+1) + \
           self.then.indented(level+1)


class If_Else_AST:
  def __init__(self,  condition,  then,  otherwise):
    self.condition = condition;
    self.then = then;
    self.otherwise = otherwise;
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'if ' + repr(self.condition) + ' then ' +\
                    repr(self.then) + ' else ' + \
                    repr(self.otherwise) + ' end'
  def indented(self,  level):
    return indent('If-Else',  level) + \
            self.condition.indented(level+1) + \
            self.then.indented(level+1) + \
            self.otherwise.indented(level+1)

class While_AST:
  def __init__(self, condition, body):
    self.condition = condition
    self.body = body
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'while ' + repr(self.condition) + ' do ' + \
                      repr(self.body) + ' end'
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('While', level) + \
           self.condition.indented(level+1) + \
           self.body.indented(level+2)

class Assign_AST:
  def __init__(self, identifier, expression):
    self.identifier = identifier
    self.expression = expression
  def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.identifier) + ':=' + repr(self.expression)
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('Assign', level) + \
           self.identifier.indented(level+1) + \
           self.expression.indented(level+1)

class Write_AST:
  def __init__(self, expression):
    self.expression = expression
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'write ' + repr(self.expression)
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('Write', level) + self.expression.indented(level+1)

class Read_AST:
  def __init__(self, identifier):
    self.identifier = identifier
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'read ' + repr(self.identifier)
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent('Read', level) + self.identifier.indented(level+1)

class Comparison_AST:
  def __init__(self, left, op, right):
    self.left = left
    self.op = op
    self.right = right
  def __repr__(self):
    op = { Token.LESS:'<', Token.EQ:'=', Token.GRTR:'>',
           Token.LEQ:'<=', Token.NEQ:'!=', Token.GEQ:'>=' }
    return repr(self.left) + op[self.op] + repr(self.right)
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent(self.op, level) + \
           self.left.indented(level+1) + \
           self.right.indented(level+1)

class Expression_AST:
  def __init__(self, left, op, right):
    self.left = left
    self.op = op
    self.right = right
  def __repr__(self):
    op = { Token.ADD:'+', Token.SUB:'-', Token.MUL:'*', Token.DIV:'/' }
    return '(' + repr(self.left) + op[self.op] + repr(self.right) + ')'
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent(self.op, level) + \
           self.left.indented(level+1) + \
           self.right.indented(level+1)

class Number_AST:
  def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.number
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent(self.number, level)

class Identifier_AST:
  def __init__(self, identifier):
    self.identifier = identifier
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.identifier
  def indented(self, level):
    return indent(self.identifier, level)

# The following methods comprise the recursive-descent parser.

def program():
  sts = statements()
  return Program_AST(sts)

def statements():
  result = [statement()]
  while scanner.lookahead() == Token.SEM:
    scanner.consume(Token.SEM)
    st = statement()
    result.append(st)
  return Statements_AST(result)

def statement():
  if scanner.lookahead() == Token.IF:
    return if_statement()
  elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.WHILE:
    return while_statement()
  elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.ID:
    return assignment()
  elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.READ:
    return read();
  elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.WRITE:
    return write();
  else: # error
    return scanner.consume(Token.IF, Token.WHILE, Token.ID)

def if_statement():
  scanner.consume(Token.IF)
  condition = comparison()
  scanner.consume(Token.THEN)
  then = statements()
  if scanner.lookahead() == Token.END:
    scanner.consume(Token.END)
    return If_AST(condition, then)
  else:
    scanner.consume(Token.ELSE)
    otherwise = statements()
    scanner.consume(Token.END)
    return If_Else_AST(condition, then,  otherwise)

def while_statement():
  scanner.consume(Token.WHILE)
  condition = comparison()
  scanner.consume(Token.DO)
  body = statements()
  scanner.consume(Token.END)
  return While_AST(condition, body)

def assignment():
  ident = identifier()
  scanner.consume(Token.BEC)
  expr = expression()
  return Assign_AST(ident, expr)

def read():
  scanner.consume(Token.READ)
  i = identifier()
  return Read_AST(i)

def comparison():
  left = expression()
  op = scanner.consume(Token.LESS, Token.EQ, Token.GRTR,
                     Token.LEQ, Token.NEQ, Token.GEQ)
  right = expression()
  return Comparison_AST(left, op, right)

def write():
  scanner.consume(Token.WRITE)
  e = expression()
  return Write_AST(e)

def expression():
  result = term()
  while scanner.lookahead() in [Token.ADD, Token.SUB]:
    op = scanner.consume(Token.ADD, Token.SUB)
    tree = term()
    result = Expression_AST(result, op, tree)
  return result

def term():
  result = factor()
  while scanner.lookahead() in [Token.MUL, Token.DIV]:
    op = scanner.consume(Token.MUL, Token.DIV)
    tree = factor()
    result = Expression_AST(result, op, tree)
  return result

def factor():
  if scanner.lookahead() == Token.LPAR:
    scanner.consume(Token.LPAR)
    result = expression()
    scanner.consume(Token.RPAR)
    return result
  elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.NUM:
    value = scanner.consume(Token.NUM)
    return Number_AST(value)
  elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.ID:
    return identifier()
  else: # error
    return scanner.consume(Token.LPAR, Token.NUM, Token.ID)

def identifier():
  value = scanner.consume(Token.ID)
  return Identifier_AST(value)

# Initialise scanner.

scanner = Scanner(sys.stdin)

# Show all tokens in the input.

#token = scanner.lookahead()
#test = ''
#
#while token != None:
#    print(scanner.consume(token))
#    token = scanner.lookahead()
#

#Call the parser.
ast = program()
if scanner.lookahead != None:
  print(ast.indented(0))
exit()

#if scanner.lookahead() != None:
#   raise Exception('end of input expected but token ' +  repr(scanner.lookahead()) + ' found')

# Show the syntax tree with levels indicated by indentation.
```

Any hints on how to fix my code would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my original scanner only printed the ID and NUM Tokens, and never actually read them. So by changing my scanner so that it didn't just `return "NUM " + current[1]`, I assigned `current[1]` to a variable so that I could return it later at the end of the `consume()` method. This way, the parser was able to see if it was an ID or NUM without printing it.

I also changed my `if_statement()` and `while_statement()` methods to check if the next token was `end`, `else`, `while`, or `if`. Upon not finding any of those, the method was to assume the next token was an assignment, therefore searching for the `Token.ID` or `Token.NUM`.

Comment: A problem I also came across with is that the `skip_white_space()` method is very, very temperamental. Once the sample input gets longer than 7 lines, it refused to scan anything. Also, for the language that this parser can recognize, you have to be very wary about where you place your semicolons.